# H5BP Ant-contrib 1.1.1 not working

Tags: ant, html5boilerplate

When I update to ant build script V1.1.1 in a known successful v1.0 file, the script runs through to "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", but the publish directory is incorrect. CSS appears to be compressed OK. Main.js is mangled, but empty. HTML files are not compressed. Terminal (OSX 10.9.5)reports the following error message:

```
-htmlcompress:
 [echo] Run htmlcompressor on the HTML
 [echo]  - removing unnecessary whitespace
 [echo]  - removing html comments
 [echo]  - compressing inline style/script tag contents
[apply] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.compress(Ljava/io/Writer;IZZZZ)V
[apply]     at com.googlecode.htmlcompressor.compressor.YuiJavaScriptCompressor.compress(YuiJavaScriptCompressor.java:54)
[apply]     at com.googlecode.htmlcompressor.compressor.HtmlCompressor.compressJavaScript(HtmlCompressor.java:975)
[apply]     at com.googlecode.htmlcompressor.compressor.HtmlCompressor.processScriptBlocks(HtmlCompressor.java:910)
[apply]     at com.googlecode.htmlcompressor.compressor.HtmlCompressor.processPreservedBlocks(HtmlCompressor.java:800)
[apply]     at com.googlecode.htmlcompressor.compressor.HtmlCompressor.compress(HtmlCompressor.java:221)
[apply]     at com.googlecode.htmlcompressor.CmdLineCompressor.process(CmdLineCompressor.java:275)
[apply]     at com.googlecode.htmlcompressor.CmdLineCompressor.main(CmdLineCompressor.java:109)
[apply] Result: 1
```

Did V1.1.1 make changes beyond updating yuicompressor? I don't see anything in v1.1.1 project.xml that needs changing from V1.0. What am I missing here?